# Word Choice Conundrum Followup

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling

In my initial post I may have not made my issue clear enough, so...

Say out loud the sentence, "There are three ways to spell the word two."

Obviously there is only one way to spell that specific word, but it has several homophones.  When **writing** the sentence, what spelling would you replace **TWO** with?  I know it can be rephrased to make it easy, but I want the spelling for this specific example.

Comment: It's best practice to edit former questions with clarifications rather than ask new ones which aim for the same goal. Anyway, as I commented on your original question: when you are *writing* about speech *sounds*, you use a phonetic transcription (the IPA currently being the most popular choice), specifically *because* using the lexemes proper creates this kind of ambiguity (or conundrum, as you say). The proper, correct answer to your question is what I said the first time: "*There are three ways to spell the word /tu/*".

Comment: Ah, but a philosophical question -- if you use /tu/, should it really be ***the** word /tu/*? You're counting ways of spelling but not words; they're different lexemes, after all.

Comment: @JohnLawler Yeah, on his original question, basically everyone who engaged with it told him his trouble is self-created: he wants to say *the* but refer to three distinct things. That his desideratum is paradoxical, I cannot fix for him. :)

Comment: @JohnLawler: So, should the OP word the sentences as follows - Say out loud the sentence, "There are three ways to spell the homophone /tu/"?

Comment: @rhetorician: _There are at least three English words pronounced /tu/; they are spelled differently, in at least three ways._

Comment: @JohnLawler: I guess I should've added the words "phonetically transcribed," as in, "There are three ways to spell the homophone which is phonetically transcribed as 'tee you.'" My version: 15 words; your version, 18 words. Mine's a bit more parsimonious, yes? (I'm just busting your chops, John!) Don

Comment: Phonemically, not phonetically. And it's not needed because of the slashes in /tu/. Plus, which word is **the** homophone?

Answer (score -2):

Answer is "2". This way you avoid all three ways.

Comment: .... except "2" isn't a word.

Comment: Yes. But if we read the question we could find that such point was not specified :)

Comment: It certainly was: he wants to use the phrase "*there are three ways to spell **the word** X*", and he explicitly said he does not want to re-arrange the sentence in any way.

Comment: Yes, it certanly was, but it was in the quotation. And this quotation means some play of sense with writing :)

Comment: No, that is not what quotation means: quotation means you are mentioning something, not using it, and not playing with it. You are mentioning something so you can *talk about it*; but that doesn't grant some magical license to mischaracterize it. If I say "the cat 'Big Bird'  has very long whiskers", the quotes don't give me the right to call a bird a cat.